# How to create a Super Privileged User in cPanel? so that I can create a database by PHP script without phpMyAdmin dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cpanel

I am making a Multi-tenant application using Laravel. In development, localhost was enabled to create each tenant new database but when I deployed the application on cPanel creating new database showing error like,
"Access denied, you need at least one super privileged user".

Is there any way to create a superuser who can create a database without any access denied?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the Cpanel in the database section there is phpMyAdmin for MySQL\MariaDB or phpPgAdmin for PostreSQL.
also
**mysql_secure_installarion** - create password for root user (did you create it in the database wizard?)
then you can create a user using sql queries
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#create-user-overview